# How can I update vmc so that it uses cfoundry 0.5.0 instead of 0.4.21?

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry, vmc

I am trying to connect to a mysql service on cloudfoundry. I installed vmc v 0.4.7 (which is currently the latest). I have deployed my grails application and created a mysql service through it also.
Now I want to access the mysql service. I tried to perform the steps as listed here:
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

I installed caldecott also. But when i do `vmc tunnel` I get a response saying that I need to install the `tunnel-vmc-plugin`. I did that, and `tunnel-vmc-plugin` (v 0.2.0) got installed. 
Now when I do `vmc tunnel` I get an error saying that there is a conflict between `cfoundry 0.4.21` (which is required by `vmc 0.4.7`) and `cfoundry 0.5.0` (which is required by `tunnel-vmc-plugin 0.2.0`). If I try to uninstall any one `cfoundry`, the other gems that need that particular `cfoundry` version go haywire.
If you go to the git repository for `tunnel-vmc-plugin` at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc-plugins/blob/master/tunnel/tunnel-vmc-plugin.gemspec 
you will see there is a tiny link that asks you to [bump cfoundry to 0.5.0](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc-plugins/commit/b73ae4ecbfae3a7c599373384f8a2deb6d00358a)

How can I do this? Read a lot on the web about gem files, etc. but I have never learnt ruby and very little information about vmc plugins also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it.

Yes the trick is to do `gem install vmc --pre` but every dependency that this vmc needs also needs to be installed with the `--pre`.
Amazingly, I searched and searched and searched and NO WHERE on the ENTIRE WEB is this specifically mentioned. For the rest of you who are stuck, first uninstall all the following gems: 
 - cfoundry
 - tunnel-vmc-plugin
 - manifests-vmc-plugin
 - mothership
 - caldecott-client
 - caldecott
 - vmc

Once you have done this, then reinstall each one of the above plugins with the `--pre` command. Eg 
`gem install cfoundry --pre`

Please update the documentation Burt Beckwith and others who are working to build cloud foundry! Newbies like me who know nothing of ruby have a real hard time setting things up!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the easiest way to resolve this is to install the pre release version by using the --pre switch with gem;

gem install vmc --pre

Comment: hi .. thanks for the reply. i ran the above command but now i get an error saying `Unable to resolve dependencies: vmc requires cfoundry (< 0.6, >= 0.5.1.rc5), manifests-vmc-plugin (~> 0.6.2.rc1), tunnel-vmc-plugin (~> 0.2.1.rc3)`. And the latest version of cfoundry is 0.5.0!